# Discord.js Foreach loop add/removing roles

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a simple command that quickly adds a certain role to all server members (or remove, depending on the command used), but I'm having a bit of an issue.

Current code:

```
  try {
    message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).forEach((member) => {
    member.removeRole(role)
  });
    console.log(`Role ${role.name} taken from everyone!`)
  } catch {
    error => console.log(error)
  }
```

This works, but I get a lot. And I mean A LOT of errors. Mostly time errors, such as timeout: error removing role.

It says in the start that there's too much listeners, so I went online to find this .setMaxListeners(0);
But it doesn't do anything

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the behavior you described is because Discord.js needs to make so many calls to the same API endpoint concurrently, and only a certain amount can be processed at once. The loop is going through each member and calling your method again and again, and Discord.js winds up putting all these requests into a queue. When it has to wait too long to add the role, the error you see is returned. And about having too many listeners attached and the possible memory leak warning, Discord.js attaches a listener for when Discord says the role is actually removed. Because your code isn't waiting for the role to be removed for each member, a lot are attached at once.

Even if you wanted to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the `member.removeRole()` call, it wouldn't work in a `forEach()` loop because of the way it's built. It doesn't wait for your function to finish, so it just keeps going and then moves on. A [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop would fix this issue.

The best solution in this case might actually be to clone and then delete the role. By deleting it, it's automatically removed from every member, and you don't have to make all those calls to the API or wait for all of them. To "clone" it, you can create a new role using the old role instance as the data, adding 1 to the position (assuming the old role is there).

Also, just as a side note, the `catch` block of a `try...catch` statement doesn't use a callback function. The code inside of it is read and executed just like in the `try` block (only if there's an error of course). And, if you're not `await`ing promises, your `catch` block won't actually catch rejections because everything may have already moved on (the promise is pending, so it just continues).